# I don't have the previous code on my Linear one button garage opener remote where can I get it

Tags: electrical

Where can I get the codes for one button Linear garage remote for a Chamberlin Formula 1?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Chamberlain Website](https://support.chamberlaingroup.com/s/article/How-to-program-a-remote-control-1484145515533), you dont need any codes.

> **Program Using Your Garage Door Opener LEARN Button**
>
> 1. Locate the LEARN button on the garage door opener.
> 2. Press and immediately release the LEARN button. The LEARN LED will glow steadily.
> 3. Within 30 seconds, press the button on the remote control that you wish to operate your garage door.
> 4. The garage door opener lights will flash or two clicks will be heard. The remote control is programmed.

You can also find all the manuals on the site.

Comment: _Here, let me DuckDuckGo that for you..._ Sheesh... (for the OP, not the answer)